# Convert String to Binding<String> in Swift

Tags: swift, string, data-binding

Most of the solutions I see are partaining to **SwiftUI** where a string can be passed as a Binding String like this

```
TextField("", $text)
```

But in this case, it's purely on Swift... I have this code below

```
final class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
    var text: Binding<String>

    init(text: Binding<String>) {
        self.text = text
    }
    
    func myFunc(){
        let string = "my string" // a dynamically created String
        self.text = string // This throws an error that I cannot assign value type of string to Binding<String>
    }
}
```

How can I get to convert `String` to `Binding<String>`?

Comment: `Binding` is only for SwiftUI `View`s, it doesn't work in a class, leave it in the parent

Comment: This is a custom `TextField` in SwiftUI, so the other end of the data binding is coming from a SwiftUI page... My purpose of doing this is that I want to be able to edit some of the text as the user is typing and display it back to the user.

Comment: Look into using @Published in a class that conforms to `ObservableObject`, this is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `Coordinator` suggests that we are talking about `UIViewRepresentable`.

If so the usual way is to declare the Binding in the `UIViewRepresentable` struct and pass the `MyView` instance to the coordinator to have access to it

```
struct MyView: UIViewRepresentable
{
    @Binding var text: String
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
...
```

---

```
final class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
    var parent: MyView

    init(_ parent: MyView) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func myFunc(){
        let string = "my string" // a dynamically created String
        parent.text = string
    }
}
```